# Change the default action once JSDoc generates the documentation

Tags: documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

In the process of reviving and updating documentation for a project at my workplace, I've encountered an unexpected behavior while using JSDoc.

When I run the command `jsdoc -c jsdoc.json`, upon completion, it automatically opens a browser and attempts to navigate to https://www.npmjs.com/package/nameOfMyProject.

**My questions are:**
Where can I find and configure this behavior in the JSDoc or better-docs settings?

I have been searching in the documentation for both projects and I can´t find any reference to this.